# Need to understand why the regex is not replacing all matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out the following regex expression and why it is giving me the result I am getting.

I have the following javascript:

```
let result = '7979797'.replace(/797/g,'77');
```

I would have expected result to have the value of 7777 but instead it has a value of 77977.

I was hoping someone could explain why I am getting a value of 77977 and what I would need to change to the regex to get it replace all strings that have the patter 797 to 77.

Comment: regex by default won't do overlapping matches. Without consider the overlapping, you have two `797`, so that it would be replaced with `77`

Comment: Use a loop instead. Do the replace while the pattern matches.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a regex replaces the first `797` with `77`, it doesn't rescan the material it has replaced (the `77`), so it sees `9` next, then `797`, leading to the result you get.

Comment: A side note, the regex to replace all matches can be achieved with a lookahead function.  let result = '7979797'.replace(/79(?=7)/g, '7');

Answer (score 3):

As a alternative we can use below code to achieve desired effect.

```js
var input = '7979797';
var reg = /797/;
while(reg.test(input)){
    input = input.replace(reg,'77')
}
console.log(input)
```